# Chrome extensions do not respect browser_specific_settings

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

The W3C Browser Extensions Community Groups has been working for a while on compatibility between browser extensions on different platforms (Chrome/Firefox/Edge/Opera/Etc.).

They have a [list of keys](https://browserext.github.io/browserext/#list-of-keys) which should be safe to use. An important one being `browser_specific_settings` so you can specify proprietary settings for different browsers without the manifest being marked as ill-formed.

I need to add an ID for my Firefox addon under this key, but **Chrome is not supporting this** out of the box and shows an error if the extension is installed - **Is there a way to tell Chrome to ignore this key?** (without scaring the user that the extension is broken when it isn't)

Comment: No there isn't. And Google doesn't care about that coordinated effort like totally. You'll have to provide a separate build of your extension for Chrome.

Comment: That's the second time you've confirmed something for me - thank you

Comment: Do you have a source for that "Google doesn't care"? That strikes me as a big assumption given how some Google teams do work with other browsers quite a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was originally confirmed in a comment

> No there isn't. And Google doesn't care about that coordinated effort like totally. You'll have to provide a separate build of your extension for Chrome. –
> [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)